# Run a function on multiple html elements having same class name

Tags: javascript, html

*****Working**
When i right click on the chat item then it run a function test_delete(e) for target element and context menu shows and store chat id in variable x.

when we click on delete then it shows the id of target chat.
works fine for now.

**Problem**
If i click on a chat 10 times or more than 1 time
and then i click on delete from context menu then the delete button function returns chat id per click on chat

but i want it return only single  chat id

Example: if i click on chat 10 time but click delete button 1 time then it return chat id of last targeted chat 10 times but
I want it return chat id only 1 time

if You dont understant my question then run snippet and view console

How can i fix this problem....

---

```js
  //CHAT CONTEXT MENU FOR Desktop

    function test_delete(e){
    let menu = document.getElementById('m');
    let mes = document.getElementById('dM');

        menu.style.display = "block";
     y = e.currentTarget;
        let check_user = e.currentTarget.className;
        if (check_user == 'to') {
          //  alert("You Click on " + check_user);
        }
       // console.log(e.currentTarget.className);
        x = y.querySelector('input').value;
         // console.log(e);
          if(e.pageX == undefined){
            var posX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
            var posY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
          }
          else{
            var posX = e.pageX;
            var posY = e.pageY;
          }
         
        

        var menuWidth = menu.offsetWidth;
        var menuHeight = menu.offsetHeight;
        var totalWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var totalHeight = window.innerHeight;

        if ((totalWidth - posX) < menuWidth) {
            menu.style.left = posX - menuWidth + "px";
            //console.log("ifX = ");
        } else {
            menu.style.left = posX + 5 + "px";
           //  console.log("elseX = ");
        }
        if ((totalHeight - posY) < menuHeight) {
            menu.style.top = posY - menuHeight + "px"
              //   console.log("ifY = ");
        } else {
            menu.style.top = posY + "px";
           //  console.log("elseY = ");
        }
        var contextItem = document.getElementsByClassName('context-item');
        var contextLength = contextItem.length;
        var i= 0;
        for(i;i<contextLength;i++){
            contextItem[i].addEventListener('click', function(){menu.style.display='none';
            
        })
            
        }
        window.onclick = function(e) {
            if(!e.target.matches.menu){
                menu.style.display = "none";
            }
           
          
            
    }
    //console.log(inner);
        menu.querySelector('#Tex').addEventListener("click", function() {
            
            let data = `id=${x}`;
            console.log(data);
        
        });


    }

    //CHAT CONTEXT MENU FOR TOUCH DEVICES
    function mobileContext(){
     var chatBody = document.getElementsByClassName('from');
    // console.log('ChatBody = '+chatBody);
    var chatBodyLength = chatBody.length;
    var i=0;
     var delay = 500;
     var holdStarter = null;
     var holdActive = false;
     for(i;i<chatBodyLength;i++){
        chatBody[i].addEventListener('touchstart' , TouchStart);
        chatBody[i].addEventListener('touchend' , TouchEnd);
        chatBody[i].addEventListener('auxclick' , test_delete);
     }

     

     function TouchStart(){
        holdStarter = setTimeout(function() {
            holdStarter = null;
            holdActive = true;
        }, delay);
     }

     function TouchEnd(e){
        if (holdStarter) {
            clearTimeout(holdStarter);
            // run click-only operation here
            // console.log('Clicked!');
        }else
        if(holdActive == true){
          //  console.log('Hold Active');
            
            holdActive = false;
            test_delete(e);
        }
     }
    }
    mobileContext();
```

```css
 .TestClass {
      /*  left: -89px; */
        position: absolute;
        width: 140px;
        
        background: #ffffff;
        z-index: 1000;
        /* border: 1px solid green; */
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px -3px #00000024;
        display: ;
        border: 1px solid #dbdee7;
    }

    p.innerP0 a:last-child {
        border: 0;
    }

    p.innerP0 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: gray;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        font-size: 11px;
        border:none; 
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    p.innerP0 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 4px 0px !important;
    }

    p.innerP0 a:hover {
        background: #c9c9c9;
    }

    #dM {
        padding: 5px 15px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: #4849a1;
        color: #fff;
        font: 300 12px/1 'open sans';
        width: fit-content;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: -40px;
        margin: auto;
        transition: .5s ease;
    }
    .to123f {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        position: relative;
    }
    .to123f p {
        padding: 12px 10px;
    }
    .to123f p {
            font-size: 13px;
            -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .from{
        background:gray;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        }
```

```html
<!--Context Menu-->    
 <div class="TestClass" id="m">
       <p  class="innerP0">
           
       <a  class="context-item" id="Tex">Delete</a>
       <a class="context-item" id="EDIT">Edit...</a>
       <a class="context-item" id="forward">Forward</a>
       <a class="context-item" id="copy">Copy</a>
       <a class="context-item" id="copy">Select</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <p id="dM"></p>




<!--Html Elements of same class name-->

<div class="to123f">
   <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="263">
        <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>
        <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">fgdfg</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="to123f">
   <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="264">
        <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>
        <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">dffdg</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="to123f">
   <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="266">
        <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>
        <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">
asad
</p>
    </div>
</div>



  


    <!--Html Elements of same class name-->

    <div class="to123f">
       <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">

            <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="263">

            <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>

            <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">fgdfg</p>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="to123f">

       <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">

            <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="264">

            <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>

            <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">dffdg</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="to123f">

       <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">

            <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="266">
            <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>
            <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">
asad
</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding event listeners in test_delete()? Event listeners are automatically called when there is an event, such as a mouse click. Hence adding them only once is enough. Moving all addEventListener() statements to mobileContext() should solve your problem.

```js
//CHAT CONTEXT MENU FOR Desktop

    function test_delete(e){
      let menu = document.getElementById('m');
      let mes = document.getElementById('dM');

      menu.style.display = "block";
      y = e.currentTarget;
      let check_user = e.currentTarget.className;
      if (check_user == 'to') {
        //  alert("You Click on " + check_user);
      }
      // console.log(e.currentTarget.className);
      x = y.querySelector('input').value;
      // console.log(e);
      if(e.pageX == undefined){
        var posX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        var posY = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
      } else {
        var posX = e.pageX;
        var posY = e.pageY;
      }

      var menuWidth = menu.offsetWidth;
      var menuHeight = menu.offsetHeight;
      var totalWidth = window.innerWidth;
      var totalHeight = window.innerHeight;

      if ((totalWidth - posX) < menuWidth) {
        menu.style.left = posX - menuWidth + "px";
        //console.log("ifX = ");
      } else {
        menu.style.left = posX + 5 + "px";
        //  console.log("elseX = ");
      }
      if ((totalHeight - posY) < menuHeight) {
        menu.style.top = posY - menuHeight + "px"
        //   console.log("ifY = ");
      } else {
        menu.style.top = posY + "px";
        //  console.log("elseY = ");
      }
    }

    //CHAT CONTEXT MENU FOR TOUCH DEVICES
    function mobileContext(){
      var chatBody = document.getElementsByClassName('from');
      // console.log('ChatBody = '+chatBody);
      var chatBodyLength = chatBody.length;
      var i=0;
      var delay = 500;
      var holdStarter = null;
      var holdActive = false;
      for(i;i<chatBodyLength;i++){
         chatBody[i].addEventListener('touchstart' , TouchStart);
         chatBody[i].addEventListener('touchend' , TouchEnd);
         chatBody[i].addEventListener('auxclick' , test_delete);           }

      let menu = document.getElementById('m');
      var contextItem = document.getElementsByClassName('context-item');
      var contextLength = contextItem.length;
      for(var i = 0;i<contextLength;i++){
        contextItem[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
          menu.style.display='none';  
        })           
      }
      
      window.onclick = function(e) {
        if(!e.target.matches.menu){
          menu.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
      
      //console.log(inner);
      menu.querySelector('#Tex').addEventListener("click", function() {            
        let data = `id=${x}`;
        console.log(data);
      });
     

     function TouchStart(){
        holdStarter = setTimeout(function() {
            holdStarter = null;
            holdActive = true;
        }, delay);
     }

     function TouchEnd(e){
        if (holdStarter) {
            clearTimeout(holdStarter);
            // run click-only operation here
            // console.log('Clicked!');
        }else
        if(holdActive == true){
          //  console.log('Hold Active');
            
            holdActive = false;
            test_delete(e);
        }
     }
    }
    mobileContext();
```

```css
.TestClass {
      /*  left: -89px; */
        position: absolute;
        width: 140px;
        
        background: #ffffff;
        z-index: 1000;
        /* border: 1px solid green; */
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px -3px #00000024;
        display: ;
        border: 1px solid #dbdee7;
    }

    p.innerP0 a:last-child {
        border: 0;
    }

    p.innerP0 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: gray;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        font-size: 11px;
        border:none; 
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    p.innerP0 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 4px 0px !important;
    }

    p.innerP0 a:hover {
        background: #c9c9c9;
    }

    #dM {
        padding: 5px 15px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: #4849a1;
        color: #fff;
        font: 300 12px/1 'open sans';
        width: fit-content;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: -40px;
        margin: auto;
        transition: .5s ease;
    }
    .to123f {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        position: relative;
    }
    .to123f p {
        padding: 12px 10px;
    }
    .to123f p {
            font-size: 13px;
            -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .from{
        background:gray;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        }
```

```html
<!--Context Menu-->    
 <div class="TestClass" id="m">
       <p  class="innerP0">
           
       <a  class="context-item" id="Tex">Delete</a>
       <a class="context-item" id="EDIT">Edit...</a>
       <a class="context-item" id="forward">Forward</a>
       <a class="context-item" id="copy">Copy</a>
       <a class="context-item" id="copy">Select</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <p id="dM"></p>




<!--Html Elements of same class name-->

<div class="to123f">
   <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="263">
        <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>
        <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">fgdfg</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="to123f">
   <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="264">
        <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>
        <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">dffdg</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="to123f">
   <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">
        <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="266">
        <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>
        <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">
asad
</p>
    </div>
</div>



  


    <!--Html Elements of same class name-->

    <div class="to123f">
       <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">

            <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="263">

            <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>

            <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">fgdfg</p>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="to123f">

       <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">

            <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="264">

            <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>

            <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">dffdg</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="to123f">

       <div class="from Text_chat" oncontextmenu="return false;">

            <input class="chatId" type="hidden" value="266">
            <span class="chatf_time">2022-01-16 21:32:37</span>
            <p id="message_detail" class="chat_text fromuser">
asad
</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Superbe....!  Thanks man you are great dev.   Now my problem is solved...